# Chain code Container - how to monitor container running on container in pod?

Tags: containers, blockchain, hyperledger, smartcontracts

I am trying to monitor health check for chain code container running on peer container.

It is not running on Kubernetes with other container like peer, orderer. 
Chain code container is running on peer node after all other container have creation.

The reason for this is to detect any deployment failure of specific version of chain code on blockchain network.

I heard that there is a way to do it by using logs of peer container. But I want to know if it can work by checking container itself.

Any comment will be appreciated.